# How to smooth and make thinner these very rough images using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, smoothing

I have some black and white images of a single digit. I am using a NN model trained on MNIST to classify them. However, the digits are too rough and thick compared to the MNIST dataset. For example:

[image]

TLDR: I need to smoothen image and possibly make overall shape thinner using OpenCV.

Comment: This is too broad/vague, and off topic. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely benefit from [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html). Specifically it sounds like you want erosion.

You do have some noise though. You should try OpenCV's [smoothing operations](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html). Based on my experience, I think you need to use a median blur with a kernel area of maybe around 9 (although it depends on what you want). Then you need to use erode.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of morphology close, open and erode (and optionally skeletonize and dilate) in Python/OpenCV as follows:

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

# load image
img = cv2.imread("5.png")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology erode
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (21,21))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("5_thinned.png", thresh)

# skeletonize image and dilate
skeleton = cv2.threshold(thresh,0,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
skeleton = (255*skeletonize(skeleton)).astype(np.uint8)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
skeleton_dilated = cv2.morphologyEx(skeleton, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("5_skeleton_dilated.png", skeleton_dilated)

cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("RESULT1", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT2", skeleton_dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result1 (close, open, erode):

[image]

Result2 (close, open, erode, skeletonize, dilate):

[image]